# Symfony 4 own form theme not loading

Tags: twig, symfony4

I need a form theme for one field. I don't want to load it in the form _self.

So i did in config/packages/twig:

```
twig:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/templates']
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    form_themes: 
        - 'form/calendarFormtheme.html.twig'
```

My form theme templates/form/calendarFormtheme.html.twig:

```
{%- block calendar_widget -%}
<div class="ui inline calendar" id="calendar_start">
    <div class="ui disabled input left icon">
        <i class="calendar icon"></i>
        <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" placeholder="hallo" {% endif %}/>
    </div>
</div>
{%- endblock calendar_widget -%}
```

And in my formType:

```
 $builder->add('start', DateTimeType::class, [
            'block_name' => 'calendar_widget',
            'label' => false,
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'attr' =>  [
                'data-provide' => 'calendar',
                'data-date-format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm'
            ]
        ]);
```

But it's not loading the new theme. 
Where is my mistake?

TXH

Comment: is `form/calendarFormtheme.html.twig` extending a [base Symfony form theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#reusing-parts-of-a-built-in-form-theme)? Also please show the template that calls `form_start(form)`

Comment: i extend the ` form_div_layout.html.twig ` - It still uses the ` {%- block datetime_widget -%}  . Not my ` calendar_widget  `

Comment: please update your question to show how you are using the `{% extends %}` or `{% use %}` declarations for the form theme, as well as the entire twig template that is calling `{{ form_start(form) }}` and if it extends any other templates, what is declared in them. A manual call to `{% form_theme %}`  in the parent templates will negate your `config/packages/twig` configuration `form_themes`.